# How do I issue a warning message from PowerShell that does not require user input

Tags: powershell

I am running a batch script that invokes a .exe file, if the file is not present then I wish to issue a warning, similar to the system.windows.messagebox class, but without the need for the user to respond, because I want the batch script to continue to run without pausing for user interaction. I tried this via powershell

PowerShell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework;[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Application not found','Warning',1,48)"

But this requires user response, and I can't seem to find any way around this as the message box class does not seem to have the option to bypass the user response. Is there any other class I can invoke, or any other utility I can invoke for DOS/Powershell for this?

Thanks in advance for any responses you may give.

Comment: How about calling `Write-Warning`?

Comment: As an update,, Installshield invokes the system.windows.messagebox class via the function  MessageBox ( szMsg, nType );
The nytpe can have values
• INFORMATION
• WARNING
• SEVERE
The INFORMATION option just displays the warning message box without requiring any user interaction that would delay the script execution. So I figured that Powershell should also be able to invokes the system.windows.messagebox class in the same manner, but I can't find how to do this from the PowerShell documentation I have.

Comment: Hi Matthias yes thanks I did consider Write-Warning but this will only be visible if the executing command window (i,e the batch script that invokes the powershell utility) is directly being viewed by the user. In which case I might as well just use the @echo command in the batch script. However this may not be the case as the user would often minimize or hide the execution of the batch script while performing parallel tasks. The reason I want to use the system.windows.messagebox class  is that it issues a warning popup message that is directly visible to the user in all cases

Answer (score 0):

It might be tempting to try and hack together a non-blocking version of `[MessageBox]::Show(...)`, but the much simpler solution is to dispatch the call in a separate runspace - this way you won't be blocking the main thread of the default runspace and your script can continue in the background.

To create and use a separate runspace:

```
# create and open separate runspace
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.Open()

# create a [PowerShell] instance, this will act as a container for the messagebox code
$ps = [powershell]::Create()
$ps = $ps.AddScript({
  [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Application not found", 'Warning', 1, 48)
})

# assign $ps to the separate runspace
$ps.Runspace = $rs

# invoke script asynchronously (this avoids blocking the main runspace while waiting for the new one)
$null = $ps.BeginInvoke()
```

The remainder of the script will continue immediately, unabated by the modal messagebox shown.

Make sure to clean up the runspace after the main script ends (this will still block until the user responds to the message box):

```
try {
  $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
  $rs.Open()
  $ps = [powershell]::Create()
  $ps = $ps.AddScript({
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Application not found", 'Warning', 1, 48)
  })
  $ps.Runspace = $rs
  $null = $ps.BeginInvoke()

  # code to install application (or whatever you need to do while the messagebox is shown) goes here
}
finally {
  # clean up
  $ps,$rs |Where-Object { $_ -is [IDisposable] } |ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: @RaresDima Not if you don't fill in the "code to install application". Alternatively call `Wait-Event` after `BeginInvoke`

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside Start-Job, as simple as that:

```
function Show-WarningPopup {
    param (
        [string]$message,
        [string]$title
    )
    $popupJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($using:message, $using:title, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)
    }
}

Show-WarningPopup -message "You have been warned!" -title "Title"
```